# Get query results to group_by in model form and get placed in select

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, modelchoicefield

I have a model form and I'm trying to get a dropdown to populate the select with options from the database.

My model form looks like this:

```
class CreateTripsForm(forms.Form):
    start_locations = Mileage.objects.values('start_location').annotate(num_locations=Count('start_location')).order_by('start_location')
    end_locations = Mileage.objects.values('end_location').annotate(num_locations=Count('end_location')).order_by('end_location')
    starting_location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=start_locations, empty_label=None)
    ending_location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=end_locations, empty_label=None)
```

The select options are there, but they give results that are not what I'm after. The options in the select look like this:

```
{'start_location': 'Location A', 'num_locations': 27}
{'start_location': 'Location B', 'num_locations': 27}
{'start_location': 'Location C', 'num_locations': 27}
```

I just want the select to only show:

```
Location A
Location B
Location C
```

I've tried a number of different ways to accomplish this, but I feel I'm missing something.

Edit:

Mileage model looks like this:

```
class Mileage(models.Model):
    miles = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=1)
    start_location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    end_location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.miles
```

Comment: and what have you tried?? post that code. and also tell there are 2 choice fields, which is returning which ans?

Comment: I've tried a few things unsuccessfully - very minor changes that ultimately would prove fruitless to provide here as they were small changes to essentially just this code.

Comment: just tell me a thing, 2 fields have 2 different result right? {'start_location': 'Location A', 'num_locations': 27} or this is coming in whole for one field?

Comment: Can you post your Mileage Model? Please include the `__str__` and/or `__unicode__` methods

Comment: @Exprator - that whole thing is coming in for one field. I updated the question with my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to display two selects with different properties of the same model. By default, `ModelChoiceField` uses the `__str__` method of the `QuerySet` values, in this are dictionaries because you are calling `values` before the `annotate`.

Don't use `values` in the queryset, or use a `ModelForm` instead of `ModelChoiceField`

Comment: Yeah - I see now that I can use `values_list` to get a list and flatten it to get just pure values in list format instead of Tuples.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by changing my queryset.

Instead of using `.values` I changed it to `.values_list('start_location', flat=True)` and now it's giving me the list of the names I want in the select forms appropriately.

Comment: maybe you need to use `.values_list('id', 'start_location', flat=True)`, to use the `id` as the `value` in the rendered options.